# SQL management studio 2012 table from an other database keep coming back automatically

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am learning T-SQL. Every time I create a new database, table from a deleted database keep on appearing automatically. :-( don't know how to stop it.

Comment: Ok let me explain. I first created a database then created the table using new query. when I clicked on execute it showed(Command(s) completed successfully.). After I deleted the database and created a new one again. on the new database the tables from the first database was already there and every time I create a database the same thing happened.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  New databases are "copies" of the model database.  So I'm guessing that you accidentally added this rogue table to the model database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the System Database -> Model.  Delete the table from there.  Then create a new database and it should "appear" again.

Comment: Thanks for your help i managed to drop the table in the model database.